# LexikFormFilterBundle KnpPaginationBundle Symfony3

Tags: symfony

the pagination does not include the filter only page param is appended.

the doctrine stuffs works and the results are filtered on the first post,
but the pagination is not working.

does it require any additional configuration?

My Controller:

```
    $qb = $userRepository->createQueryBuilder('product')
        ->andWhere('product.shop = :shop_id')
        ->andWhere("product.uuid != ''")
        ->setParameter("shop_id", $selectedShop->getUid())
        ->orderBy('product.uid', 'ASC');

    $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class);
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $this->get('lexik_form_filter.query_builder_updater')->addFilterConditions($form, $qb);
    }

    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $query = $qb->getQuery(),
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
        15
    );


    return array(
        'pagination' => $pagination,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    );
```

My SearchFormType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('term', TextFilterType::class, array(
            'apply_filter' => function (QueryInterface $filterQuery, $field, $values) {
                if (empty($values['value'])) {
                    return null;
                }

                $filterQuery->getQueryBuilder()
                    ->andWhere("
                        to long ...
                    ");
            })
        );
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'item_filter';
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'csrf_protection'   => false
    ));
}
```